MySQL Query for Values Active in One Table and Not the Other
Let's say I have table with the following information:
Inventory of books that are either in stock or no longer in inventory.
Then, let's say there is another table that indicates if anyone has ownership of the book. This table could show that multiple people previously owned the book, but the status is "deleted" for each person who sold that same book indicating they no longer own it. If a 4th person currently owns it, then it would show an "active" status for that person in the table.
There is also a timestamp indicating when each person sold a book.
Here is some sample data:
book_inventory table



id
book_inventory_id
status
book_name
return_date




1
111
active
Frankenstein
2024-08-12


2
222
active
Harry Potter
2023-04-15


3
333
active
The Lord of the Rings
2024-08-10


4
444
deleted
The Odyssey
2024-02-01



book_ownership table



id
book_inventory_id
status
book_name




1
111
active
Frankenstein


2
222
deleted
Harry Potter


3
222
deleted
Harry Potter


4
222
active
Harry Potter


5
333
deleted
The Lord of the Rings


6
333
deleted
The Lord of the Rings


7
444
deleted
The Odyssey



As you can see, the book_ownership table contains multiple records for the same book_inventory_id value meaning that has remained in inventory, though it has gone through several owners with id = '4' being the current owner.
Question: How do I write a MySQL query to find books that currently have no active owner that are active in the book inventory? In the example above, only "The Lord of the Rings" is without a current owner and active in the book inventory.

The query
select book_inventory.*
from book_inventory
left join book_ownership
on book_inventory.book_inventory_id = book_ownership.book_inventory_id and book_ownership.status = 'active'
where book.inventory.status = 'active' and book.ownership.id is null

Explanation:

we select from book_inventory
left joining with book_ownership so we will have proper matches between inventory and ownership as well as inventory items that have no match
in the on clause we define what we consider a match, which is a match in book_inventory_id value and an ownership status of active
but in the where clause we filter out all inventory items that have a match, so only the items without a match are left in there among the results
and of course we ensure that we have the correct inventory status

